# Using PHP while loop instead of a js array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, calendar

I'm currently working on an event calendar php project. I got this open source calender script from [Github - Calendrio](https://github.com/codrops/Calendario/) which enables adding events to the calendar but it calls its event data from the variable 'codropsEvents' in "data.js". Now I want events to be called dynamically from mysql database.

FUNCTION CALLING THE CALENDAR SCRIPT (Notice the Caldata : codropsEvents)

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function() {

            var transEndEventNames = {
                    'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                    'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                    'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                    'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                    'transition' : 'transitionend'
                },
                transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ],
                $wrapper = $( '#custom-inner' ),
                $calendar = $( '#calendar' ),
                cal = $calendar.calendario( {
                    onDayClick : function( $el, $contentEl, dateProperties ) {

                        if( $contentEl.length > 0 ) {
                            showEvents( $contentEl, dateProperties );
                        }

                    },
                    caldata : **codropsEvents**,
                    displayWeekAbbr : true
                } ),
                $month = $( '#custom-month' ).html( cal.getMonthName() ),
                $year = $( '#custom-year' ).html( cal.getYear() );

            $( '#custom-next' ).on( 'click', function() {
                cal.gotoNextMonth( updateMonthYear );
            } );
            $( '#custom-prev' ).on( 'click', function() {
                cal.gotoPreviousMonth( updateMonthYear );
            } );

            function updateMonthYear() {                
                $month.html( cal.getMonthName() );
                $year.html( cal.getYear() );
            }

            // just an example..
            function showEvents( $contentEl, dateProperties ) {

                hideEvents();

                var $events = $( '<div id="custom-content-reveal" class="custom-content-reveal"><h4>Events for ' + dateProperties.monthname + ' ' + dateProperties.day + ', ' + dateProperties.year + '</h4></div>' ),
                    $close = $( '<span class="custom-content-close"></span>' ).on( 'click', hideEvents );

                $events.append( $contentEl.html() , $close ).insertAfter( $wrapper );

                setTimeout( function() {
                    $events.css( 'top', '0%' );
                }, 25 );

            }
            function hideEvents() {

                var $events = $( '#custom-content-reveal' );
                if( $events.length > 0 ) {

                    $events.css( 'top', '100%' );
                    Modernizr.csstransitions ? $events.on( transEndEventName, function() { $( this ).remove(); } ) : $events.remove();

                }

            }

        });
    </script>
```

I changed the 'codropsEvents' with the php function 'getEvents' which i included on my page head. Below is the replaced line and my php function but the calendar doesn't show up

```
caldata: { <?= getEvents(); ?> },



// The getEvents() function


$query_rsgetevents = "SELECT * FROM calendar_events";
$rsgetevents = mysql_query($query_rsgetevents, $rsCalData) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsgetevents = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsgetevents);
$totalRows_rsgetevents = mysql_num_rows($rsgetevents);

function getEvents() {
$i=0;
while ($i< $totalRows_rsgetevents) {

$month=mysql_result($rsgetevents,$i,"event_month");
if(strlen($month) < 2) { // this is incase only 1 digit was enter e.g. month 5 instead of 05
$month = "0" . $month;
}
$day=mysql_result($rsgetevents,$i,"event_day");
if(strlen($day) < 2) {
$day = "0" . $day;
}
$year=mysql_result($rsgetevents,$i,"event_year");
$title=mysql_result($rsgetevents,$i,"event_title");
if ($i < $totalRows_rsgetevents -1) {
echo "'$month-$day-$year' : '$title'";
} else {
echo "'$month-$day-$year' : '$title'";
}
$i++;
}
}
```

OR IS THERE ANY BETTER WAY TO DO THIS?

Comment: You are probably getting an error in JavaScript. Open developer tools (F12) and look at the console tab to see what it is. I wouldn't be surprised if you have one of the `$title` with an apostrophe in it and it is breaking the json output. You are generally better off adding the data to an array and then using `json_encode` to convert to json. Also you are doing a double echo which might be an issue. Your function is echo'ing, but returns nothing and when calling the function you are using `<?=` which is short hand "open php and echo". So you are echo'ing the return from the function.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanKuhn ..But I'm not really good at json.. I would appreciate any help. Regards